# Matching one or more non-] characters in Vim's search?

Tags: regex, search, vim

I need to match a string of characters that doesn't contain `]`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I searched for "class" as in "char class" but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this pattern to search for any string that doesn't contain **]** character:

**PATTERN**

```
/^[^\]]+$/
```

Also more details about vim and regex:

[vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Type the below characters in Vim and you can search any line which does not contain `]`

```
/[^\]]*
```

Comment: `any line which does not contain` should be changed to `any character which is not`